# Issue with the operator like

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form which i use it to search specific records from the database.

This is the query:

```
$sql = "select * from `hostess` where first_name_en like '%$term' or family_name_en like '%$term%' order by `family_name_en` asc";
```

The issue is that if i search i.e *ele* there come all the names which contain *ele*, such as *elena*, etc etc, but if i write *elena* nothing comes up.

**How come**?

Comment: There must be some other error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you didn't use the `%` at the end of the `first_name_en` value ?

```
$sql = "select * from `hostess` where first_name_en like '%$term%' or family_name_en like '%$term%' order by `family_name_en` asc";
```

**Edit :** For the uppercase-lowercase problem :

```
$term = strtolower($term);
$sql = "select * from `hostess` where lower(first_name_en) like '%$term%' or lower(family_name_en) like '%$term%' order by `family_name_en` asc";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missing a % in your first LIKE. 
At present your saying search for any first name that ends in ele.

1. `LIKE '%ele'` - will match anything that ends in ele
2. `LIKE 'ele%'` - will match anything that begins with ele
3. `LIKE '%ele%'` - will match anything with ele in it

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, but even if i do so, it still won't be able to find what i need. it is because the term doesn't match the field in the database, some are lowercase some are uppercase
How can i do for it to be not sensitive to the letters?

Comment: @Tao you can look at my edited answer for your case sensitive problem

Comment: Ok in that case you need to change the colation: try this: WHERE firstname_en COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE '%$term%'

Comment: @codea mysql does not perform case-sensitive checks, by default.

Comment: Or you could format the data you selecting with to be lower case and wrap your column in LOWER(COLUMN) - EX WHERE LOWER(first_name_en) LIKE '%$term%'

Comment: @coder1984 the default is case insensitive, but depending on the collation of the table it can be case sensitive

Comment: @RyanS true, dint think of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select * from `hostess` where first_name_en like '%$term%' or family_name_en like '%$term%' order by `family_name_en` asc";
```

**%$term%**

**Use This**